# Deshabilitar boton tipo submit con jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo un botón tipo *submit* para enviar un formulario y dirigirme a otra página:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnlog" class="btn btn-lg" value="" >Ingresar</button>
```

y al desabilitar el boton con jquery

```
$('#btnlog').click(function () {
        $('#btnlog').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

No carga la otra pagina que debería ir. Si quito la acción *jquery* del botón funciona perfecto y me lleva a la otra página.

Comment: y cual es el problema?? que esperas que realice??

Comment: Edite la pregunta.

Comment: pero en tu código estas diciendo que cuando se haga click en el botón se deshabilite el  mismo botón. No decís que carge otra pagina ni nada.

Comment: el boton es para enviar un formulario y me va a otra pagina. cuando le doy se desactiva el boton pero no me carga la pagina. si quito el jquery se envia el formulario si problema

Comment: claro. porque estas definiendo un evento que cuando se haga click haga tal acción. Si no podes ese codigo, hace el evento de enviar un formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo así te va a servir

```
$("#submitId").closest('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#btnlog').attr('disabled', true);
    this.submit(); // ahora hace el submit de tu formulario.
});
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio tu respuesta! ahora como haria con jquery si un campo   no es un numero para que se cancele al cargar la pagina?

Comment: Por nada. Si te sirvió el problema podrías poner como solucionado. Ahora si tenes otra pregunta crea un nuevo post, para no estar mezclando las cosas. Gracias